# Can I initialise a std::vector<T*> from a list of instances?

Tags: c++

I have some objects like this:

```
Obj o1{};
Obj o2{};
Obj o3{};
...
```

However, I also have another class `Foo` which has a `std::vector<Obj*>` as a member.

How can I initialise the `vector` from an arbitrary list?

I would like to construct Foo like this:

```
Foo f{o1, o3, o4};
```

I have tried this knowing that I can't have collections of references.

```
    class Foo {
    public:
        explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<Obj&> px) {
            for (auto& p : px) {
                fwds.push_back(&p);
            }
        }

        ...

    private:
        std::vector<Obj*> fwds;
    };
```

The error I get in this case is:

```
... include\initializer_list(25,1): error C2528:  'abstract declarator': pointer to reference is illegal
```

Comment: what happened when you tried? any errors?

Comment: Looks fine to me, what was the outcome?

Comment: btw collections cannot hold references directly, but there is `std::reference_wrapper` which exists for just that purpose afaik

Comment: Since you're using an `initializer_list` the instances you point to probably don't exist anymore by the time you get around to trying to use them.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: @formerlyknownas_463035818 You can't have an array of references and that is what `std::initializer_list` would try to build.

Comment: do you really want `fwds` to hold pointers?

Comment: Is there any reason you wouldn't want to just have that initializer list accept `Obj*` instead of `Obj&`? (`Foo f{&o1, &o2, &o3};`)

Comment: Thanks for all the help here. I've updated the question with the error message. I'm trying `std::reference_wrapper`. I'm just wanting the conceit of `f{o1, o3, o4};` and yes I can use c++17, so I've just updated the tags.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

With `std::reference_wrapper`, you might do:

```
explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<Obj>> px) {
    for (auto& p : px) {
        fwds.push_back(&p.get());
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/11917a58b6e48cf4)

Note: You might also want to promote your members to `std::vector<std::reference_wrapper<Obj>> fwds;`, which simplify the constructor too.

Comment: I wonder why it was downvoted, I think this is correct answer.

Comment: I didn't vote, but I would at least warn that it is unconventional to keep referring to objects passed into constructor by reference (except for types for which it is obvious such as reference_wrapper itself).

Comment: @eerorika: Yes, you are right to warn about this. I could end up with dangling pointers. In my case though, all the objects seen here have exactly the same lifetime.

Comment: @eerorika: With abstract name as `Foo`, hard to say if lifetime would be an issue or not. BTW, storing reference is done even more with lambda now.

Comment: @Jarod42 indeed, because of the abstract name the warning is warranted. If it was something non-abstract like "class reference_vector", the warning would be unnecessary.

Answer (score 5):

You could do it this way:

```
class Foo {
public:
    template <typename... Objs,
         std::enable_if_t<(std::is_base_of_v<Obj, Objs> && ...), int> = 0>
    explicit Foo(Objs&... o)
        : fwds{&o...}
    { }
private:
    std::vector<Obj*> fwds;
};
```

which in C++20 becomes:

```
class Foo {
public:
    explicit Foo(std::derived_from<Obj> auto&... o)
        : fwds{&o...}
    { }
private:
    std::vector<Obj*> fwds;
};
```

Comment: Blast, just beat me and with a better answer.  +1

Comment: `std::is_same` might be too restrictive though, as class with `operator Obj&` would be rejected.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yeah, derivation is probably better. Not too concerned about `operator Obj&()`.

Comment: Forgot the simple failing case :-/ but traits/concept can be adapted to the needs anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to pass a list of pointers explicitly:

```
explicit Foo(std::initializer_list<Obj*> px) : fwds(px) {}
//...
Foo f{&o1, &o3, &o4};
```

Comment: `std::initializer_list<Obj*>` would allow `nullptr`, which may be not fine though :-/

Comment: Good point Jarod. Maxim still gets an upvote for me just for the simplicity.

Comment: @Jarod42 `std::reference_wrapper<Obj>` doesn't really prohibit `nullptr` either, since one can unwittingly dereference a null pointer to construct a `std::reference_wrapper<Obj>`. But the latter might give some people a false sense of security, I give you that.

Comment: Deferencing nullptr is UB, so you got UB before creating a potential `std::reference_wrapper` containing nullptr.

Comment: @Jarod42 I wrote _**unwittingly**_. Most UB happens unwittingly and `std::reference_wrapper<Obj>` doesn't help you a bit to prevent or detect that UB.

Comment: With pointer, `Foo` **has** to check/handle `nullptr` case, with `std::reference_wrapper`, it is the caller responsibility (and `Foo` cannot even check that).

Comment: @Jarod42 Now we are discussing where that `nullptr` check should be because `std::reference_wrapper<Obj>` doesn't help against `nullptr`. It is good that this understanding has been established now. If you insist on the `nullptr` check then the best place for it is in `Foo`, so that its users don't have to repeat that tedious check over and over.

Comment: In OP's usage (`Foo f{o1, o2, o3}`), there are no checks to do at all as no pointers involved.

Comment: @Jarod42 My answer doesn't involve null pointers either. Why did you bring this null pointer issue up, since `std::reference_wrapper<Obj>` is neutral to null pointers?

Comment: You accept `nullptr` as input, so should be handled for safety. (or at least `std::initializer_list<gsl::not_null<Obj*>>` to document that nullptr is invalid input).